# Regex to Validate Phone Numbers in php

Tags: php, regex

I know there are lots of same type of questions posted on stackoverflow but I have something in custom and dont know how to solve this problem.

If any number is prefixed with ‘+’ or 0 (sequence of zero like 00) or ‘91-‘, then it should be removed automatically before group creation. 
prefixed needs to be removed -

1. 0 or sequence of 0 (00, 000, 0000 etc)
2. +
3. 91-
4. +91-

Valid mobile numbers entered by users should be as below:

1. If mobile number is 10 digit, it should start with 9,8,7 or 6
2. If mobile number is 12 digit, first 2 digits should be 91 and 3rd digit should be 9,8,7 or 6  All other numbers should be considered invalid for domestic group creation.

What will be the php code for above as will be?

phone no ex-

1. `+918877665544 or 0918877665544 or 0000918877665544 will give 918877665544` (length 12)
2. `+91-8877665544 or 91-8877665544 or 00008877665544 will give 8877665544` (length 10)
3. `+91-88776655440 (length 11) or 91-88-77665544 (- in between) will give gets skip or should giv blank`

only digits are allowed after removing the allowed prefixes.

if any other it should skip (should give blank).

*Note:-* for all the cases it should have only one regex as this regex will be inserted from config settings.

Comment: You are asking for multiple things here.  One, you want to format the input numbers a certain way, and two, you want to validate them using a regex.  Please show us sample valid input phone numbers which cover all edge cases.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I have edited my question with some example please have a look.

Comment: I would just go with something like `(?:[+]?0*(?:91-?)?)?([6-9][0-9]{9})` and look at the first capture group

Comment: Of course you need to add the ^ and $ anchors to ensure it matches the whole string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option could be using optional parts at the start of the pattern:

```
^\+?0*(?:91-)?\K(?:91)?[6-9][0-9]{9}$
```

- `^` Start of string
- `\+?0*(?:91-)?` Optionally match `+`, 0+ times a `0` or `91-`
- `\K` Forget what was matched
- `(?:91)?` Optionally match `91`
- `[6-9][0-9]{9}` Match a digit 6-9 and 9 digits 0-9
- `$` End of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/r5Svve/1) | [Php demo](https://3v4l.org/hS7bj)

If you don't want to use anchors `^` and `$` you could use lookaround assertions to make sure what is directly on the left and right is not a non whitespace char:

```
(?<!\S)\+?0*(?:91-)?\K(?:91)?[6-9][0-9]{9}(?!\S)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/IhSkOs/1) | [Php demo](https://3v4l.org/aG0kc)

Comment: I have huge set of numbers in array format. Do I need to change them to string format break by line or there is any other solution to this?

Comment: @VikasChauhan I have added an update to the answer.

Comment: Could you please update the php demo code ?

Comment: @VikasChauhan  have added another php demo for the second regex.

Comment: Wouldn't this match `91-918877665544`?

Comment: @NullUserException Yes it is giving it as a valid number but it should be an invalid one

Comment: In the question it states `+91-8877665544 or 91-8877665544 or 00008877665544 will give 8877665544`. Is that not correct?

Comment: This matches `91-918877665544`, which should be an invalid number